# google-cloud-profiler metadata server WARNING

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-profiler

I am trying to use **Google Cloud Profiler** in a python script running locally. It seems it is having problems to connect with a **metadata server**:

> WARNING:googlecloudprofiler.client:Failed to fetch **instance/zone** from GCE metadata server: HTTPConnectionPool(host='metadata', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
>
> WARNING:googlecloudprofiler.client:Failed to fetch **instance/name** from
>   GCE metadata server: HTTPConnectionPool(host='metadata', port=80): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /computeMetadata/v1/instance/name (Caused
>   by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
>   or service not known',))

Since the app seems to be running correctly and the profiler is collecting data successfully, is it OK if I just ignore the warnings or will I likely encounter some problems in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running locally (and haven't, for example, manually zone in the config), these warnings are expected, so ignoring them is definitely okay.

(Disclosure: I work at Google on Stackdriver Profiler)